# Download images from an image board based on tags and blacklists

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, json, network-file-transfer

This code is meant to download images from an image board to create a local backup. Images are grouped by tags selected by the user and then downloaded using multiprocessing. Normal use of this program would be daily or weekly, resulting in a typical download queue of no more than 100. However, if the user opts to download images from all time which match their query, the queue can grow up to 100,000. The way I have it written now uses tuples. This is not a problem in some cases, but it is extremely slow parse and can cause crashes on machines with smaller memory pools. In addition to that major flaw, it is one of my first python programs, so I expect it to be messy and/or hacky in a few other places.

It is a fairly large project, which has only grown larger and messier as I think of new features for it, but I trust the stack exchange community a lot when it comes to issues I have. It might even be a ton larger than necessary for what it tries to accomplish.

**Main**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
import os
import sys
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
from collections import namedtuple
from lib import constants, support, api, downloader

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()

    logging.basicConfig(level = support.get_verbosity(), format = constants.LOGGER_FORMAT,
        stream = sys.stderr)
    LOG = logging.getLogger('program')
    LOG.info('Running program version ' + constants.VERSION + '.')

    CONFIG = support.get_config('config.ini')

    early_terminate = False
    early_terminate |= not downloader.internet_connected()
    early_terminate |= support.validate_tags(CONFIG)

    if early_terminate:
        LOG.info('Error(s) occurred during initialization, see above for more information.')
        sys.exit(-1)

    GROUP = namedtuple('Group', 'tags directory')
    blacklist = []
    tag_groups = []

    LOG.info('Parsing config for blacklist and settings.')

    for section in CONFIG.sections():
        if section == 'Settings':
            pass
        elif section == 'Blacklist':
            for tag in CONFIG.get('Blacklist', 'tags').replace(',', '').split():
                blacklist.append(api.get_alias(tag))
        else:
            for option, value in CONFIG.items(section):
                if option == 'tags':
                    tag_groups.append(GROUP(value.replace(',', ''), section))

    LOG.info('program will look for new posts since ' +
        CONFIG.get('Settings', 'last_run') + '.')
    print ''

    download_list = []

    for group in tag_groups:
        LOG.info('Checking for new posts tagged: \"' + group.tags.replace(' ', ', ') + '\".')

        accumulating = True
        current_page = 1
        links_missing_tags = 0
        links_blacklisted = 0
        links_on_disk = 0
        will_download = 0
        post_list = []
        tag_overflow = []

        separated_tags = group.tags.split()

        if len(separated_tags) > 5:
            search_tags = ' '.join(separated_tags[0:5])

            for tag in separated_tags:
                if tag not in search_tags.split():
                    tag_overflow.append(api.get_alias(tag))

        else:
            search_tags = group.tags

        while accumulating:
            links_found = api.get_posts(search_tags, CONFIG.get('Settings', 'last_run'),
            current_page, constants.MAX_RESULTS)

            if not links_found:
                accumulating = False

            else:
                post_list += links_found
                accumulating = len(links_found) == constants.MAX_RESULTS
                current_page += 1

        if len(post_list) > 0:
            for i, post in enumerate(post_list):
                LOG.debug('Item ' + str(i) + '\'s id is \"' + str(post.id) + '\".')

                filename = support.make_filename(group.directory, post)
                current_tags = post.tags.split()

                if len(separated_tags) > 5 and not list(set(tag_overflow) & set(current_tags)):
                    links_missing_tags += 1
                    LOG.debug('Item ' + str(i) + ' was skipped. Missing a requested tag.')

                elif list(set(blacklist) & set(current_tags)):
                    links_blacklisted += 1
                    LOG.debug('Item ' + str(i) + ' was skipped. Contains a blacklisted tag.')

                elif os.path.isfile(filename):
                    links_on_disk += 1
                    LOG.debug('Item ' + str(i) + ' was skipped. Already downloaded previously.')

                else:
                    LOG.debug('Item ' + str(i) + ' will be downloaded.')
                    download_list.append((post.url, filename))
                    will_download += 1

            LOG.info(str(will_download) + ' new files. (' + str(len(post_list)) + ' found, ' +
            str(links_missing_tags) + ' missing tags, ' + str(links_blacklisted) +
            ' blacklisted, ' + str(links_on_disk) + ' duplicate.)')
            print ''

        else:
            LOG.info('0 new files.')
            print ''

    if download_list:
        LOG.info('Starting download of ' + str(len(download_list)) + ' files.')
        downloader.multi_download(download_list, CONFIG.getint('Settings',
            'parallel_downloads'))
        print ''
        LOG.info('Successfully downloaded ' + str(len(download_list)) + ' files.')
    else:
        LOG.info('Nothing to download.')

    CONFIG.set('Settings', 'last_run', constants.YESTERDAY.strftime(constants.DATE_FORMAT))
    CONFIG.write(open('config.ini', 'w'))

    sys.exit(0)
```

**Constants**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime

DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"
YESTERDAY = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal() - 1)
LOGGER_FORMAT = "%(name)-11s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s"
MAX_RESULTS = 100
VERSION = '3.0.2 -- Forked from 2.4.6'

DEFAULT_CONFIG_TEXT = ''';;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; MAIN SETTINGS ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[Settings]
last_run = ''' + YESTERDAY.strftime(DATE_FORMAT) + '''
parallel_downloads = 8

[Blacklist]
tags =

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; TAG GROUPS ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; New tag groups can be created by writing the following:
; [Directory Name]
; tags = tag1, tag2, tag3, ...
;
; Example:
; [Cute Cats]
; tags = cat, cute'''
```

**Support**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import logging
import os
import ConfigParser
from urllib import FancyURLopener
import constants

class SpoofOpen(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.0.12) ' + \
        'Gecko/20070731 Ubuntu/dapper-security Firefox/1.5.0.12'

def get_verbosity():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog = 'program', description = 'An automated image downloader.')

    verbosity = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required = False)
    verbosity.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action = 'store_true', help = 'Display full debug \
        information while running.')
    verbosity.add_argument('-q', '--quiet', action = 'store_true', help = 'Display no output while \
        running, except for errors.')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.quiet:
        return logging.ERROR
    elif args.verbose:
        return logging.DEBUG
    else:
        return logging.INFO

def make_config(filename):
    LOG = logging.getLogger('config')

    with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(constants.DEFAULT_CONFIG_TEXT)
        LOG.info('New default file created: \"' + filename + '\".')

def get_config(filename):
    LOG = logging.getLogger('config')
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        LOG.error('No config file found.')
        make_config(filename)

    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        config.readfp(infile)
        return config

def validate_tags(config):
    LOG = logging.getLogger('tags')

    sections = 0
    for _ in config.sections():
        sections += 1

    if sections < 3:
        LOG.error('Please add at least one tag group to \"config.ini\".')
        return True
    else:
        return False

def substitute_illegals(char):
    illegals = ['\\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '\"', '<', '>', '|', ' ']
    return '_' if char in illegals else char

def make_filename(directory_name, post):
    safe_directory = ''.join([substitute_illegals(char) for char in directory_name]).lower()
    name = str(getattr(post, 'id'))

    if not os.path.isdir('downloads/' + safe_directory.decode('utf-8')):
        os.makedirs('downloads/' + safe_directory)

    filename = 'downloads/' + safe_directory + '/' + name + '.' + post.ext

    return filename
```

**API**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
from json import loads
from collections import namedtuple
from support import SpoofOpen

Post = namedtuple('Post', 'url id ext tags')
UserTag = namedtuple('UserTag', 'alias_id name')
AliasedTag = namedtuple('AliasedTag', 'name')

LOG = logging.getLogger('api')

def get_posts(search_string, uploaded_after, page_number, max_results):
    request = 'https://x.json?' + \
        'tags=' + search_string + \
        ' date:>' + str(uploaded_after) + \
        '&page=' + str(page_number) + \
        '&limit=' + str(max_results)

    LOG.debug('Post request URL: \"' + request + '\".')

    results = loads(SpoofOpen().open(request).read().decode())

    posts = []
    for post in results:
        posts.append(Post(post['file_url'], post['id'], post['file_ext'], post['tags']))
    return posts

def download_post(url, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(SpoofOpen().open(url).read())

def get_alias(tag):
    request = 'https://x.json?query=' + tag
    LOG.debug('Tag alias request URL: \"' + request + '\".')

    results = loads(SpoofOpen().open(request).read().decode())

    user_tags = []
    for user_tag in results:
        user_tags.append(UserTag(user_tag['alias_id'], user_tag['name']))

    if not user_tags:
        LOG.error('The tag \"' + tag + '\" does not exist, please remove it from your tags ' +
            'file or blacklist.')
        return ''

    if tag == user_tags[0].name:
        request = 'https://x.json?id=' + str(user_tags[0].alias_id)
        LOG.debug('Tag official request URL: \"' + request + '\".')

        results = loads('[' + SpoofOpen().open(request).read() + ']'.decode())

        aliased_tags = []
        for aliased_tag in results:
            aliased_tags.append(AliasedTag(aliased_tag['name']))

        LOG.debug('Tag \"' + tag + '\" aliased to \"' + aliased_tags[0].name + '\".')
        return aliased_tags[0].name

    else:
        return tag
```

**Downloader**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
import urllib2
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Process
from time import sleep
from support import SpoofOpen

def internet_connected():
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen('http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt', timeout = 5)
        return True
    except urllib2.URLError:
        pass
    LOG = logging.getLogger('internet')
    LOG.info('No internet connection detected.')
    return False

def update_progress(downloaded, total):
    progress = float(downloaded) / float(total)

    BAR_LENGTH = 36
    status = ''
    if isinstance(progress, int):
        progress = float(progress)
    if progress < 0:
        progress = 0.0
        status = ' -- Stopped.\n'
    if progress >= 1:
        progress = 1.0
        status = ' -- Done.\n'
    completed = int(round(BAR_LENGTH * progress))
    progress_bar = '\rDownloading          [{}] {:6.2f}% {} {}'.format('>' * completed +
        ' ' * (BAR_LENGTH - completed), progress * 100, '(' + str(downloaded) + ' / ' + str(total) +
        ')', status)
    print progress_bar,

def download_monitor(managed_list, total_items):
    while True:
        update_progress(len(managed_list), total_items)
        if total_items == len(managed_list):
            return
        sleep(0.2)

def single_download(zipped_args):
    url_name_list, managed_list = zipped_args
    url, filename = url_name_list

    spoof = SpoofOpen()

    try:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as dest:
            source = spoof.open(url)
            dest.write(source.read())

        LOG = logging.getLogger('single_dl')
        LOG.debug('Downloading \"' + filename + '\".')
        managed_list.append(filename)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

def multi_download(url_name_list, num_threads):
    manager = Manager()
    managed_list = manager.list()

    LOG = logging.getLogger('multi_dl')
    LOG.debug('Staring download pool of ' + str(num_threads) + ' workers.')

    monitor = Process(target = download_monitor, args = (managed_list, len(url_name_list)))
    monitor.start()

    workers = Pool(processes = num_threads)
    work = workers.map_async(single_download, zip(url_name_list, repeat(managed_list)))

    try:
        work.get(0xFFFF)
        monitor.join()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

Comment: Overall your code looks fine. About memory problem, this can be fixed by making your `api.get_posts` a `generator` and start downloading/processing images as soon as you get a link for it instead of keeping this list in the memory, which results in outofmemory exception. Try to run linter like flake8 against your code, because it violates PEP8 a lot. And one more last thing use string formatting instead of concatenation because concatenation is not a python way to construct a string. The code is too big and I'm lazy too to write a proper answer where I would point each problem with an example.

Answer (score 2):

As Alex says, it looks good, but do use flake8, and consider making a generator.

I get NXDOMAIN for x.json - it wasn't clear what those DNS references were supposed to do.

After `if __name__ == '__main__':` you started defining capitalized GLOBALS and doing usual setup steps, which is fine. But then it looks like that chunk of code kept growing, at which point you should `def main` to avoid polluting the global namespace with identifiers like `section`.

Rather than your three lines, this pair of lines seems more pythonic:

```
early_terminate = (not downloader.internet_connected()
                   or support.validate_tags(CONFIG))
```

Your heart was in the right place, naming it to offer the Gentle Reader a hint, but it seems clear enough, so an `if` with that expression would suffice.

This is odd, I recommend deleting it:

```
sys.exit(0)
```

Here is the tiniest of nits: in support.py, PEP8 asks for a blank line before `import constants`. As a reader, I appreciate that you grouped your imports, I found it helpful.

I sort of expected main to crack sys.argv with

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

rather than support's get_verbosity. It left me wondering if other functions would be poking around at argv.

In the predicate validate_tags(), `sections = len(list(config.sections()))` seems more natural. Consider renaming it to `has_valid_tags()`. Consider turning the local list `illegals` into a global set that is initialized just once.

In api get_alias(), it would be natural to define user_tags with a list comprehension. Similarly for aliased_tags. Better, obtain `results`, verify it is non-empty, and then define `result` to be the only element you care about, the first one. That would simplify obtaining user_tag and aliased_tag.

You defined LOG as a global, yet you create other LOG locals, e.g.:

```
LOG = logging.getLogger('internet')
```

Consider defining a helper so you can say:

```
get_log('internet').info('No internet connection detected.')
```

Consider setting a constant to 36 in this way:

```
def update_progress(downloaded, total, bar_length=36):
    progress = float(downloaded / float(total))
```

That 2nd line should obsolete the isinstance int test.